# Dynamic dropdown list appending values on every onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have like 3 dynamic dropdown, which are getting populated on onchange event of preceding dropdown list. onchange , I am able to populate the dropdown , but the place where am facing problem is that if I alter the selection from any dropdown , the new values get appended to the succeeding dropdown previous values instead of replacing.

Below is my code:

```
 Dropdown1: <select id="ddlFiles" onchange="GetNamedItems()">
              <option diasbled="disabled">Select File</option>
             </select>
 Dropdown2: <select id="ddlNamed" onchange="GetColumns()">
 Dropdown3: <select id="ddlColumn" onchange="GetColumnsY()">

 function GetNamedItems()
 {
 for (var i=0; i <namedItem.length;++i)
 {

  var list =  document.getElementById('ddlNamed');
  var newListItem = document.createElement('OPTION');  
  var listInfo=namedItem[i];

  var box = listInfo;
 newListItem.text = box;
 newListItem.value = box;
 list.add(newListItem); 
 }}
```

Similarly for rest of the dropdowns.

Comment: Show us the code otherwise we can't give you the right answer, just speculations - you either have to change your code to `.html()` instead of `.append()` or use `.empty()`

Comment: have added my code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
function GetNamedItems() {

 var list = document.getElementById('ddlNamed');

                   $('#ddlNamed').find('option:gt(0)').remove();


for (var i = 0; i < namedItem.length; ++i) {
var newListItem = document.createElement('OPTION');
var listInfo = namedItem[i];
var box = listInfo;

newListItem.text = box;
newListItem.value = box;

list.add(newListItem);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the content before appending the new one

```
function GetNamedItems() {

  var list = document.getElementById('ddlNamed');
  list.innerHTML = '<option diasbled="disabled">Select File</option>';

  for (var i = 0; i < namedItem.length; ++i) {
    var newListItem = document.createElement('OPTION');
    var listInfo = namedItem[i];
    var box = listInfo;

    newListItem.text = box;
    newListItem.value = box;

    list.add(newListItem);

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanx Spokey for your reply, its working fine . But its also removing my 1st item of the dropdown, i.e.,  "Select". how can I retain my 1st item and then refresh the dropdown.

Comment: @Rooney you can either create the option element and append it or just write it in the inner html

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this issue yesterday with a form reset function.

The key is:

```
$(select).empty();
```

and then repopulate the drop downs . . .

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your question. Try to use .remove() before appending the new one

```
$(select).remove();
```